# Use Async/Await in event handler in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function with two arrows, which sends some form data to my api via a `POST` request with fetch, once the form gets submitted. I want to make fetch asynchronous, but I really have no clue where the `async` keyword goes in this case.

```
 //handles the submitting process
const handleSubmit = async (form_username, form_email, form_password) => (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  
    let data = {
      username: form_username,
      email: form_email,
      password: form_password,
    };

    const response = await fetch(API + "/register", {
      method: "POST",
      mode: "cors",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    });
};
```

The function would then be called via `handleSubmit(param1, param2,...);`

However, having the async keyword infront of the first params list returns the error `unexpected reserved word 'await'`

Any ideas where I should place the async keyword in order to actually make it async?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `async` is declared on the wrong function: it should be the inner function that is being returned, since it is the one that contains the `await` keyword:

```
const handleSubmit = (form_username, form_email, form_password) => async (event) => {
  // Rest of the logic here
}
```